# How can i convert stateless map component into react component

Tags: reactjs

My MyMapComponent is the stateless component, it was used the compose and with props and props. How can i convert into react component with this? My requirement is to place the code into render return function directly.

```js
const MyMapComponent = compose(
 withProps({
   googleMapURL:
     "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB-lALSE8L0zgfk0vdt73gNTsfalkAggwY&v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places",
   loadingElement: <div style={{ height: "100%" }} />,
   containerElement: <div style={{width:"100%", height: ht,}} />,
   mapElement: <div style={{ height: "100%"}} />
 }),
 withScriptjs,
 withGoogleMap
)(props => (
  <GoogleMap defaultZoom={10} defaultCenter={{ lat: 32.6804468, lng: -97.0827933 }}>
  <Marker onClick={props.onMarkerClick} position={{ lat: 32.6804468, lng: -97.0827933 }} />
   <Marker onClick={props.onMarkerClick1} position={{ lat: 32.7020541, lng: -97.2755012 }} />
   <Marker onClick={props.onMarkerClick}  position={{ lat: 32.5872886, lng: -97.0258724 }} />
   <Marker onClick={props.onMarkerClick1} position={{ lat: 35.2962839, lng: -98.2031782 }} />
   
 </GoogleMap>
));
```

Comment: Have you `import React from 'react'` and `export MyMapComponent`? that should make this a react component

Comment: what is `withScriptjs,
 withGoogleMap `?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about your requirement. If you only need the render function, then stateless function is probably the correct way to go.

However, this will most probably be what you need:

https://codesandbox.io/s/wo837p9z5

Comment: @AlluManikyam Glad to help.